# How to deal with changing close-vote reasons

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close, voting

I love seeing users edit their on hold/closed questions after getting some feedback about how to improve them, all the more so if in doing so they resolve the initial problem. However, it's not uncommon to introduce a new issue when that happens, especially if they're a new user to the site and haven't figured out exactly what the scope of the site is.

Questions are placed on-hold for a specific reason, but only reopened when all problems have been resolved. This is less-than-ideal because there's a potentially outdated banner beneath the question describing why the question is a poor fit, and that sticks around even after productive edits from the OP. A contrived example:

A question is posted to Main:

> How can we destroy the planet???

Which is clearly problematic for multiple reasons, but I personally would close this one as too-broad. The question is then edited to become:

> Which of these two world-destruction methods is cooler?

When this shows up in the reopen queue, the prompt is something like "This question was initially closed as 'too-broad'. Has this problem been resolved?" The question is no longer too-broad, but instead primarily opinion-based. I'd feel uncomfortable voting to reopen, but it's also no longer too-broad.

**How do we deal with questions that are closed for one reason, edited, and then are a poor fit for the site for a new reason? Do we care?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make thing worse, each user has a single close/reopen vote. Once it is cast, it's gone. 
This rules out the possibility of reopening because no longer too broad and then closing because primarily opinion based.

What one can do is:

- don't use the reopen vote
- leave a comment to the OP and other users, explaining the issue: the question was too broad, now the edit made it primarily opinion based, still a reason for being closed.
- address the user to the sandbox for improving the question there.
- cast the reopen vote only when the question is worth being reopened